# Carbon is clearing data

Tags: graphite, grafana, graphite-carbon

please help me in my issue. 
I made Grafana dashboard and all are working fine. But my history is erasing by itself which more then seven days. I don't know what it's can be.

carbon.conf

```
[cache]
ENABLE_LOGROTATION = True
USER =
MAX_CACHE_SIZE = inf
MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND = 500
MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE = 50
LINE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2003
ENABLE_UDP_LISTENER = False
UDP_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
UDP_RECEIVER_PORT = 2003
PICKLE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2004
USE_INSECURE_UNPICKLER = False
CACHE_QUERY_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
CACHE_QUERY_PORT = 7002
USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True
LOG_UPDATES = False
LOG_CACHE_HITS = False
CACHE_WRITE_STRATEGY = sorted
WHISPER_AUTOFLUSH = False
[relay]
LINE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2013
PICKLE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2014
RELAY_METHOD = rules
REPLICATION_FACTOR = 1
DESTINATIONS = 127.0.0.1:2004
MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10000
MAX_DATAPOINTS_PER_MESSAGE = 500
QUEUE_LOW_WATERMARK_PCT = 0.8
TIME_TO_DEFER_SENDING = 0.0001
USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True
USE_RATIO_RESET=False
MIN_RESET_STAT_FLOW=1000
MIN_RESET_RATIO=0.9
MIN_RESET_INTERVAL=121
[aggregator]
LINE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2023
PICKLE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2024
DESTINATIONS = 127.0.0.1:2004
REPLICATION_FACTOR = 1
MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10000
USE_FLOW_CONTROL = True
MAX_DATAPOINTS_PER_MESSAGE = 500
MAX_AGGREGATION_INTERVALS = 5
```

storage-schemas.conf|

```
[uptime]
priority = 100
pattern = ^uptime\.
retentions = 30s:1y,1m:2y
```

Other configuration are not using by carbon.
Please help to understand, will be happy to any help.

Comment: What do your metric names look like?  That storage-schemas.conf only addresses metrics that start with `uptime.`.

Comment: it's correct. Name is "uptime"

Comment: Name is just "uptime" ? Than it's wrong. pattern = ^uptime\. means name staring with "uptime."
It's better to have default record in any case, with pattern = .*